# how to filter phones on max texture width for an android opengl 1.0 app

Tags: android, opengl-es, filtering, textures

I have created an openGL app in android that has a few textures that I have created in different sizes (1024,1024 and 2048,2048) I picked 2048 because that's what the galaxy s3 supports. I was wondering if there is a way to filter what phones can see my app on max_texture_width I have looked at several resources

e.g.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

and couldn't find any help, I can see a lot of ways to do this programmatically such as:

[Reasonable texture sizes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031742/reasonable-texture-sizes-in-android)

but since the smaller of my textures is 1204x1024 and some graphics cards would crash on this I don't want my app to be able to get that far. Anyone got any advice on how to solve this? If I were to create a smaller texture size of 512x512 I will need an additional algorithm that I (probably) cannot write within the time constraints due to other reasons.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot filter apps by declaring max supported texture size in manifest, only on supported texture format(s).
Alternatively, you can filter your apps on Google Play per device, but there are way too much devices for you to check compatibility with.

Comment: are there any alternatives? how do I deal with this if my app tries to load a 1024x1024 texture?

Comment: Actually, 1024x1024 isn't that much for any GPU, but 4096x4096 may not work on some devices. You really should add check in code for `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and use down-sampled textures if necessary. Also loading a lot of large textures (especially with mip-maps) can cause GL error 1285 - out of memory. You may want to add checks for this case too.

Comment: ok cool, so am I alright to assume that my minimum texturesize can be 1024x1024 (this is a downscaled version of my larger texture) and check programatically for whether the Opengl can render that. should I include a further downscaled version for 512x512?

Comment: It is up to you, but I believe that a better approach is to downsample original texture programatically to supported size.

Comment: how do you do that without loading it into memory? won't it crash if I try and load my 1024x 1024 texture and then reduce the size? or is there a way of doing it differently? ahhh, so I read up a little, do I want to first load a smaller bitmap with the bitmap factory as per: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and then bind it to the openGL?

Comment: Yes the article you refer to is the most efficient way to downsample bitmaps in Android.